# Using javascript: how to create an alert window to display submitted form values?

Tags: javascript, forms, dialog, submit, alert

I appreciate the javascript helpe. I amn new to . this software as well and am loving your guy's feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

Below link example is give you idea how to submit from with JavaScript validation.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

let me know you still facing any issue.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
Name: <input type="text" Id="fname" name="fname">
<br>
Second Name: <input type="text" Id="sname" name="fname">
<br>
<input type="submit" onClick="return alertdisplay()" value="Submit">


</form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
function alertdisplay(){
var fn = document.getElementById('fname').value;
alert(fn);
var sn = document.getElementById('sname').value;
alert('Fisr Name : ' + fn + '   Secodnd Name : ' + sn);
}
</script>
```